# Which extraction method is the fastest?

Tags: r

Given list

```
li = list(a = list(b = list(1:3)))
```

the following extraction methods give identical result:

```
li[["a"]][["b"]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

purrr::pluck(li, "a", "b", 1, 2)
[1] 2

for (i in list("a", "b", 1, 2)) li = `[[`(li, i)
li
[1] 2
```

`purrr::pluck` and `for` have the obvious advantage that one can construct a vector of nested indices programmatically. Is there anything to consider when comparing them in terms of:

- performance (eg. is the "chained" `[[` method significantly different/faster from the `for` method?)
- edge cases where one way might provide a different result from the others

Comment: [microbenchmark](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) is pretty easy to use. You can use it to see which method is fastest.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I guess I'm also interested in the "under-the-hood" workings of the different approaches, not only the speed of execution. Granted, I didn't do the best job making that obvious from the title.

Comment: That risks making your question a bit too broad (but not so broad that I felt the need to vote to close it). In any event, `microbenchmark` really is fairly nice and is much easier to use than the otherwise comparable python `timeit` module.

Comment: @jakub I think thee first would be fast or use `li$a$b[[1]][2]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! I had that intuition, but was interested in what the others might be doing that's slowing them down. The answer I accepted nicely sets the `for` apart, I assume because it does a lot of extra effort each iteration. So this may be a bit anticlimactic, but I think it was still worth asking.

Comment: @jakub Another nice option is `bench::mark`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know exactly what you mean by asking *"which method is fastest"* and *"not only the speed of execution"*. If you mean asymptotic performance, then perhaps we can grow the list a bit to test. (If you mean code-elegance, idiomaticity, or something else, then perhaps it's not the clearest question.)

I have a fourth suggestion:

```r
Reduce(`[[`, list('a','b',1L,2L), init=li)
```

Performance comparison:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = li[["a"]][["b"]][[1]][[2]],
  purrr = purrr::pluck(li, "a", "b", 1, 2),
  "for" = { li0 <- li; for (i in list("a", "b", 1, 2)) li0 = `[[`(li0, i)}, 
  reduce = Reduce(`[[`, list('a', 'b', 1L, 2L), init=li)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#    base    1.5    2.65    3.747    3.60    4.95    8.9   100
#   purrr   33.9   62.00   73.727   67.70   91.90  159.1   100
#     for 2716.7 3465.65 4671.615 5120.05 5353.00 6090.2   100
#  reduce    9.6   18.60   23.519   21.50   28.10   73.5   100
```

Let's try with a larger `list`:

```r
gargantuan <- setNames(1:2600, paste0(rep(LETTERS, times=100), rep(1:100, each=26)))
li = c(gargantuan, list(a = c(gargantuan, list(b = list(1:3)))))
li[["a"]][["b"]][[1]][[2]]
# [1] 2
### other tests confirm the results are identical

# Unit: microseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#    base   35.8   74.85  132.272  142.85  194.35  211.4   100
#   purrr  102.2  210.60  313.105  354.00  396.80  519.4   100
#     for 2151.8 3082.55 4338.619 4744.00 5354.95 5841.4   100
#  reduce   40.8   94.00  160.764  177.80  223.45  239.5   100
```

This suggests that the `Reduce` solution is bested only by the literal/constant base version, and that for a *programmatic, robust* solution that `Reduce` is a bit faster than `purrr::pluck` and both eons faster than the `for` loop.

(Note: I say *robust* to mean basic indexing methods, not to error-proofing or similar. It is susceptible to the user over-indexing, so a more resilient approach might include pre-index checks and/or error-catching.)

Comment: Very nice addition of Reduce! I guess this goes to show how much additional effort the looped solution does compared to the others.

Answer (score 3):

One other point that is too long for a comment. For named lists, you can extract with a vector of names. Here your third level was named `c` to demonstrate:

```
li = list(a = list(b = list(c = 1:3)))

li[[c('a', 'b', 'c')]]
# [1] 1 2 3

li[[c('a', 'b', 'c')]][2]
# [1] 2
```

This method is slightly slower than `base` but faster than `Reduce`. On the other hand, it may not be as programatically easy as `Reduce` either and requires each level of a list to be named.

See also: 
[Replacing nested list using a vector of names of depths as an index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59042112/11355066)